# Static IP address doesn't work in docker compose v3

Tags: docker, swarm

From the official document, the static ip address should work with docker compose v3 + docker swarm. But I cannot make it work.

This is my docker compose yaml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
test:
    ipam:
    driver: default
    config:
        - subnet: 10.1.0.0/24

services:
one:
    image: mongo
    networks:
    test:
        ipv4_address: '10.1.0.100'

two:
    image: mongo
    networks:
    test:
        ipv4_address: '10.1.0.101'
three:
    image: mongo
    networks:
    test:
        ipv4_address: '10.1.0.102'
```

I use `docker stack up -c xxx.yml test` to deploy. I found the ip of the created containers are 10.1.0.3, 10.1.0.5, ...

Comment: The cause is using the `docker swarm`. In simply docker-compose you can use as you wrote. But in swarm you can't (for now). I also find out the solution to set the static IP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That works in *non*-swarm mode, but not in swarm mode. You may subscribe to [this ticket](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24170) to find out when/if support is added.

At the moment, there's an [anecdotal claim of a workaround](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24170#issuecomment-339275174), but nobody else seems to have corroborated it.